# Is it possible ? "Javascript Subclass"

Tags: javascript, class, object, subclass

I want to know i can do something "similar" to this (not working) code in javascript ?

```
function Player ()     {

    this.Inventory = function ()     {

        this.Inventory.UseItem = function(item_id)    {
            /* use the item ... */
        }

    }

}
```

and then use it like that :

```
current_player = new Player();
current_player.Inventory.UseItem(4);
```

Comment: Worth noting that the term "subclass" usually means something else in standard parlance -- 'Inventory' here is really just an object in a field on Player.

Comment: Indeed, this is composition rather than inheritance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yeah

```
function Player ()     {

    var Inventory = {


        UseItem : function(item_id)    {
            /* use the item ... */
        }

    };

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function Player() {
    this.Inventory = {
        UseItem: function(item_id) {
            // code here
        }
    };
}
```

Try that.

Answer (score 0):

```
current_player = new Player();
current_player.prototype.Inventory = {
         UseItem : function(item_id)    {
            /* use the item ... */
        }
}
```